# Can't Install Ubuntu Dual Boot With Windows 7

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot, wubi, windows-7

Two months ago I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 on my new Fujitsu laptop.
I downloaded Wubi and installed Ubuntu with it. When I restarted the computer after the installation, I got a error while trying to enter to Ubuntu:
/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr file missing or corrupt

I asked here what to do, and I was told to install Ubuntu from Live-Cd.
After I installed Ubuntu from the CD, I couldn't enter to windows 7 or the BIOS, so I couldn't reinstall windows and had to send the laptop to Fujitsu Repair Service.
Few mins ago I tried again to install Ubuntu with Wubi and I got the same error.
I very want to install Ubuntu, but I will not install ubuntu again from the CD, so please, if you can help me install Ubuntu witu wubi.

Thanks!

Comment: You've probably got a UEFI computer with GPT disks - Wubi won't work. Here's how to check if you have a GPT disk: http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2008/09/25/storage-tips-how-to-check-if-a-disk-is-a-gpt-disk.aspx (you need to run `CMD.EXE` as an administrator to run `diskpart`)

Comment: Yes, Apparently I have a GPT disk.. Is there another way to install ubuntu with wubi?
Im afraid that installing with LIVE CD will harm my laptop again..

Comment: There is no way to use Wubi with GPT disks. When you install a dual boot on a UEFI system you have to boot the Ubuntu CD/USB in UEFI mode before installing. This is very new (support came out in October), but it's apparently doable. You can review this thread for more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system